# angular material progress bar is not getting displayed

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to use progress bar but it's not getting displayed , but when i inspect i see the tags present. Following is what i have done till now. attaching the screenshot for your reference. Also i need details like i am using angular material to render all the components like table , checkbox but it still shows in old style.

my app.component.html :

```
  <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
```

checkbox :

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you import material's theme file in your styles.scss ?

Comment: Yes , I did but instead of animated progress bar it just show static . Do i need to configure it?